# Sleep command for Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, rssi, wifimanager

I am writing a small program to periodically poll the RSSI of the WIFI connection.
I am using `SystemClock.Sleep(2000)` in the program.

The problem, I would like to display the RSSI every 2 seconds. But, currently, even though it polls every 2 seconds, the result is displayed only at the end of the loop.

Here is the code snippet:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            Date dt=new Date();
            WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
            int rssi = info.getRssi();
            textStatus.append("\n\nRSSI :" +Integer.toString(rssi)); 
            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
        }
```

Would be glad, if you have some suggestion.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use sleep in the UI thread.

Do the following instead:

- create a MessageHandler (android.os.Handler) that handles messages to be displayed (`textStatus.append(...)`)
- create a working thread that runs your loop that contains the sleep
- now the working thread can't directly update the textStatus. Instead send a message from the working thread to the message handler.

**ADDED:**

Here is a useful link that might help you:

See section "Handling Expensive Operations in the UI Thread"

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading

Comment: @Kiran: see the link I added in my answer

Answer (score 0):

- Try using the stuff that you are doing in a separate thread,
- run it continuously till you require,
- make it sleep for 2sec, do your stuff,
- update the main thread from it,
- loop this process

Hope this will help a bit.